# What is the correct way to delete files/folders from my project?

Tags: eclipse, git, egit

I recently switched to using Git (eGit) from SVN... for my Eclipse Java project

as a consequence, I have many .svn folders in my source files directly

I want to delete these... but I don't think it is as simple as just deleting them using the file system, is it?

I'm afraid if I do that I might screw something up.

Should I just delete the files using Finder? (I'm on a mac)

or is there some way I'm supposed to do it using eGit?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It actually is as simple as deleting all `.svn` folders.

If you are not using SVN any more you can just delete these files. If you delete the SVN folders notice that they have the attribute `hidden` (at least under Windows).

Comment: ah, ok i will try... it is just that I tried it last night I think and then git gave me some errors.. and on next commit I think it actually recreated these deleted files... I didn't want to write this in the original question area because I'm not 100% sure this is what happened (it was late, I was tired) but I think that's what happened... does this sound familiar to anyone? or should I just go ahead and delete the files from the filesystem?

Comment: If you checked in the SVN files into git then you can drop them if you don't need them any more.

Comment: ok my (weak) understanding so far is this.. I checkout the project... delete the files locally from my file system... commit?? ... repeat this process for all my 3 branches ... am I missing something in my understanding?

Comment: I would say that's correct what you are doing, but I am not using git. Maybe someone else can help here.

Answer (score 2):

The proper way is converting the svn repo to a git repo using git-svn and then performing a clean clone, i.e. throwing away the old working directory with the .svn folders and the git-svn remainders.

Comment: thanks, good to know. For me not important though, since I was mainly only experimenting with SVN for 1 day... Git really fits my personality much better.. the plugin (eGit) looks a lot cleaner and it seems to me more stable (less finicky) than SVN (Subclipse)

Answer (score 1):

My team switched to Git weeks ago, and what I did was simply `svn export` the svn repository and then `git init` the previously exported project.
You don't really have to delete all the .svn folders in the original svn repo. Besides, if you have upgrade your svn to the several latest revisions, there would only one .svn folder just under the root directory.

Comment: these wouldn't annoy me, except for 1 major thing... when I search my files in eclipse, I get "double vision" sometimes because of old files in the .svn folders